# bash: line : docker: command not found

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell

I am using jenkins in a docker container and would like to start another instance, whenever I try to use docker command like

```
docker run -t -i ap/dashboard /bin/bash
```

I get this error:

```
bash: line 61: docker: command not found
```

How do I navigate to another container or solve this error?

I can clearly see that the vm creator was able to use the docker command by reading the  `/root/.ash_history`

here are some details about the system:

```
[-] Specific release information:
3.3.1
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.3.1
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.3"
HOME_URL="http://alpinelinux.org"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.alpinelinux.org"
```

```
 Hostname:
 b51cdbb7eebd
```

> ENVIRONMENTAL #######################################
> Environment information:
> JENKINS_VOL=/var/lib/jenkins
> JAVA_VERSION_BUILD=17
> HOSTNAME=b51cdbb7eebd
> JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR=8
> JENKINS_HOME=/opt/jenkins
> NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat
> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/java/jre/bin
> JAVA_BASE=/usr/local/java
> PWD=/
> JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre
> JAVA_PKG=server-jre
> LANG=C.UTF-8
> XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
> SHLVL=2
> HOME=/root
> PKG_URL=https://circle-artifacts.com/gh/andyshinn/alpine-pkg-glibc/6/artifacts/0/home/ubuntu/alpine-pkg-glibc/packages/x86_64
> JENKINS_VERSION=1.637
> JAVA_VERSION_MINOR=66
> _=/usr/bin/env

```
[-] Available shells:
# valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/ash
/bin/bash
```

```
[+] We can read root's home directory!
total 76
drwx------    5 root     root        4.0K Aug 28  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Nov 24 10:55 ..
-rw-------    1 root     root        3.1K Aug 29  2018 .ash_history
-rw-------    1 root     root         155 May 16  2016 .bash_history
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K May 12  2016 .oracle_jre_usage
drwx------    2 root     root        4.0K Aug 28  2018 .ssh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       46.0K Aug 28  2018 LinEnum.sh
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K May 12  2016 dockerfiles
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           0 Aug 28  2018 foo
```

> Looks like we're in a Docker container:
> 10:net_prio:/docker/b51cdbb7eebd806431ee4120d9b3ae050dbefe4a835bf2063446724572e45e30
> 9:net_cls:/docker/b51cdbb7eebd806431ee4120d9b3ae050dbefe4a835bf2063446724572e45e30
> 8:freezer:/docker/b51cdbb7eebd806431ee4120d9b3ae050dbefe4a835bf2063446724572e45e30
> 7:devices:/docker/b51cdbb7eebd806431ee4120d9b3ae050dbefe4a835bf2063446724572e45e30
> 6:memory:/docker/b51cdbb7eebd806431ee4120d9b3ae050dbefe4a835bf2063446724572e45e30
> 5:blkio:/docker/b51cdbb7eebd806431ee4120d9b3ae050dbefe4a835bf2063446724572e45e30
> 4:cpuacct:/docker/b51cdbb7eebd806431ee4120d9b3ae050dbefe4a835bf2063446724572e45e30
> 3:cpu:/docker/b51cdbb7eebd806431ee4120d9b3ae050dbefe4a835bf2063446724572e45e30
> 2:cpuset:/docker/b51cdbb7eebd806431ee4120d9b3ae050dbefe4a835bf2063446724572e45e30
> 1:name=openrc:/docker
> -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 May 16  2016 /.dockerenv

```
[-] Anything juicy in the Dockerfile:
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           617 May 12  2016 /root/dockerfiles/jenkins/Dockerfile
```

I tried many docker commands without hope

is it because that I'm already inside the container??

Comment: You do not have `docker` in the $PATH. I suspect you are in another container and want to execute `docker` inside

Answer (score 0):

Try with `docker run -t -i ap/dashboard /bin/ash`.

Maybe your container does not use `bash` so you should try with `/bin/sh` which is a symcolic link to the default installed shell processor.

Comment: docker run -t -i ap/dashboard bash
bash: line 62: docker: command not found
  same error @AntonioPetricca

Comment: Ok, I edited my post. Please, check it...

Comment: from the cat /root/.ash_history file I can see clearly that the docker command have been executed without issues

Comment: Thanks Antonio I got the same error :docker run -t -i ap/dashboard /bin/sh
bash: line 1: docker: command not found
if I change the shell to sh :: docker run -t -i ap/dashboard /bin/sh
sh: docker: not found

Comment: I edit the post again in `/bin/ash`. Please check again...

Comment: same error, is it because docker is not installed on jenkins?